# How to read data from a website using spring mvc?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC. I am trying to create a REST API in which I have to read data from a website and then parse it.
I am  so confused please help.

Answer (score 0):

The question is generic, could you tell where exactly you stopped?

Maybe you want to do something like this in your rest API:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "yourUrl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Exercicio>> listarExercicios(YourObject object) {
    object = restTemplate.getForObject("http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", YourObject.class);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(object);
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide link from where I can go through RestTemplate?

Comment: I think it can help you, a complete tutorial from where start: [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msXL2oDexqw&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTbx8p2oCgcAQGQyqN8XeA1x). At the end of the course, you will be able to create your own APIs.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: Yeah! I have understood the concept :)